# How to handle 'Tag Arrow is Protected' message in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**Background:** To support my study of Galois Theory I want to calculate Galois Groups from polynomials. This functionality is not readily available in Mma so I inquired and was advised to use the galois package in Mma ( or otherwise Sage / Pari ). The galois package can be downloaded from this location. http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2872/ ( The Galois package was written in the Mma 3 era. )

When loading the package `galois.m`, Mma displayed the following messages:

```
<<galois.m
SetDelayed::write: Tag Arrow in Arrow[Color_,{{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_}}] is Protected. >>
SetDelayed::write: Tag Norm in Norm[Poly_,a_Symbol] is Protected. >>
SetDelayed::write: Tag Norm in Norm[Poly_,{a__Symbol}] is Protected. >>
General::stop: Further output of SetDelayed::write will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

**Question:** Is a simple Unprotect of `Arrow` ( and so on ) sufficient to handle this issue? ( I have not tried yet. I want to await expert advice first before modifying any standard package ).

**EDIT**:
There are still problems after refactoring to Arrow1 ( or ArrowFnc ). This has been tested on

```
 CircleGraph[{a, b, c, d, -a, -b, -c, -d}, F];
```

( from the example in the accompanying notebook. )
does not produce a graph.

```
 CircleGraph[{a, b, c, d, -a, -b, -c, -d}, F]
```

( without ; ) produces a graph with additional text like FontForm[Symbol,18]. The arrows should contain only the text of the variables a,b,c and so on.

Further investigation shows that FontForm is terminally deprecated, this was **not detected** by Mma. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FontForm.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to replace occurrences of `Arrow` with something like `ArrowFcn`, and occurrences of `Norm` with something like `NormFcn`.

`Arrow` and `Norm` must have been added to the built-in functions after the galois package was written, so alternative names need to be used in the package.

Comment: My initial thought also but the Compatibility Checker did not even gave a warning. - Yet, the original author did not use the general accepted coding standard, i.e. don't start custom functions with caps.

Comment: \@Chris Diegen - I refactored Arrow and Norm to Arrow1 and Norm1 respectively and added Nulls to suppress warnings. This seems to have restored the functionality. I still need better function names though. Where does your Fcn stand for?

Comment: @ ndroock1, 'Fcn' is just short for Function - arbitrarily chosen.

Comment: \@Chris Diegen. - It does NOT work with Arrow after all. A simple refactor for Norm works but something goes wrong with Arrow. If you do CircleGraph[{a, b, c, d, -a, -b, -c, -d}, F]; ( from the accompanying Notebook ) nothing prints. Without the ; a lot of extra garbage is printed in the arrows. I'll EDIT the question.

Comment: @ ndroock1 - Arrow is used in `CircleGraph[]` in galois.m.  Continue with the ArrowFcn substitution, but also replace `FontForm` with `StyleForm` and `Show` with `Print` in the `CircleGraph[]` definition.